# Check a file if it's completely copied

Tags: java

I'm using java to parse XML files which come from a FTP protocol. The problem is, the file I take may being copied/modified by the FTP. So I need a method which can check whether the file is completely written.

I've tried using `File::canWrite` method (which did work at all) or finding the ending tag of the XML file but none of them works correctly at any case. The `File::renameTo` is pretty slow and doesn't look decent although it works (not all the case either). Is there any good and fast way to check a file if it's completely copied?

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer no. The best practice is to write to a file with a temporary name, for example `somefile.part` and rename it when done. The writing program needs to do that. The workaround when you don't control the writing application is to check the modification time and ensure that some reasonable time has passed since the most recent change. Perhaps a minute. Then you assume that the file is complete.